# icinga/nagios -- nrpe_check Connection refused by host

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I'm pretty new to icinga so maybe it's only a tiny problem which I don't understand....

I configured a nrpe_check command to monitor a disk on a host. This works pretty good:

```
nagios@icinga-server: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H host.mydom.com -c check_smart_attributes
OK (sda) |sda_Media_Wearout_Indicator=097;16;6
```

As you can see, the nrpe connection is working and also the script returns the right data...

But at the icinga-web frontend it says always:

```
SMART attributes CRITICAL   2014-01-31 09:25:40 0d 1h 21m 6s    4/4 Connection refused by host
```

Does anyone could help me with this problem?

Tanks, regards 
Andreas

Comment: You should post your nagios configuration, at least the `define service` and `define command` as well. This seems like you're not querying the correct host.

Answer (score 0):

Bloody typos...

After a long time and some holidays I solved the problem. I forgot a number at my IP address so it was 123 instead of 23...

Sorry for this bloody typo...

Regards Andreas

Answer (score -1):

check if you did the right thing:

```
1. /etc/icinga/ host.mydom.com.cfg
2. commands.cfg
```

Comment: Please add some code so other users can test what you're describing. Thanks!